# XML with namespaces (as XMLNS). Get specific child nodes

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I have huge XML file exported from a database of laws. (The following is an excerpt):

```
<CodiceRegionale>
     <LeggeRegionale id="urn:nir:legge:2014-12-12;26" xmlns="http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/">
         <intestazione>Legge regionale 12 dicembre 2014, n. 26 ... </intestazione>
         <articolato>
             <articolo id="art41" xmlns="http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/">
                 <num>Art. 41</num>
                 <rubrica>(Riforma della finanza locale)</rubrica>
                 <comma id="art41-com1">
                      <num>1. </num>
                      <alinea>Al fine di supportare ...</alinea>
                      <el id="art41-com1-let_a">
                          <num>a) </num>
                          <corpo>definizione di un nuovo ...</corpo>
                      </el>
                      <el id="art41-com1-let_b">
                          <num>b) </num>
                          <corpo>coordinamento ... </corpo>
                      </el>
                 </comma>
             </articolo> 
         </articolato>
     </LeggeRegionale>
</CodiceRegionale>
```

As the XML uses namespaces, I can extract the content as follows. For example I can get the content of the `<articolo id=>` like this:

```
$xml->xpath('a:LeggeRegionale[@id="urn:nir:legge:2014-12-12;26"]/a:articolato/a:articolo[@id="art41"]');
```

or the content of the `<comma id=>`:

```
$xml->xpath('a:LeggeRegionale[@id="urn:nir:legge:2014-12-12;26"]/a:articolato/a:articolo[@id="art41"]/a:comma[@id="art41-com1"]');
```

Actually I can extract all those tags that contain other tags, but I can't manage to get the content of a single open/close tag as for example `<num>` or `<rubrica>` or `<alinea>` or `<corpo>`. I thought this could work but it does not:

```
$xml->xpath('a:LeggeRegionale[@id="urn:nir:legge:2014-12-12;26"]/a:articolato/a:articolo[@id="art41"]/a:comma[@id="art41-com1"]/a:alinea')
```

Comment: i think you can directly use //el/num or //alinea like that

Comment: No. Tried, but does not work. Note that I can have hundreds of "alinea" and I need to extract only those that are child of a specific node.

Comment: try like this /CodiceRegionale//*[local-name()="el"] this will work. i given for one element apply same for all elements

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
/CodiceRegionale//*[local-name()="el"] or

/CodiceRegionale//*[@id]//*[local-name()="el"] or


/CodiceRegionale//*[@id]//*[local-name()="articolo"]
```

change accordingly avoid relative paths.

Comment: Don't understand. Would you kindly edit you answer using my last PHP string so that I can extract the `alinea` tag of that specific `articolo -> comma` tag without using `*`?

Comment: like this $xml->xpath('a:LeggeRegionale[@id="urn:nir:legge:2014-12-12;26"]/a:articolato/a:articolo[@id="art41"]/*[local-name="comma"][@id="art41-com1"]/*[local-name="alinea"]')

Comment: Nothing to do: empty array returned `Array()`. I also tried adding brackets () to local-name.

Comment: missed (). try one more time. $xml->xpath('a:LeggeRegionale[@id="urn:nir:legge:2014-12-12;26"]/a:articolato/a:articolo[@id="art41"]/*[local-name()="comma"][@id="art41-com1"]/*[local-name()="alinea"]')

Comment: I noticed the missing brackets. I added them but without success.

Comment: try relative paths. $xml->xpath('//*[local-name()="a‌​linea"]')

Comment: i tired this. it worked for me. /CodiceRegionale//*[@id]//*[local-name()="articolo"]

Comment: Yes, this works, but try to get only the content of `alinea`.

Comment: /CodiceRegionale//*[@id]//*[local-name()="comma"]//*[local-name()="alinea"]

Comment: or /CodiceRegionale//*[@id]//*[local-name()="alinea"]

Comment: Ok, but as said I have hundreds of `alinea`. I need to get those that are child of a specific tag identified by the id. How I can get the one that is child of `<comma id="art41-com1">`?

Comment: yes use it as condition /CodiceRegionale//*[@id]//*[local-name()="comma"][yourcondition]//*[local-name()="alinea"]

Comment: eg:  /CodiceRegionale//*[@id]//*[local-name()="comma"][@id="art41-com1"]//*[local-name()="alinea"]

Comment: /CodiceRegionale//*[@id]//*[local-name()="comma"][@id="art41-com1"]//*[local-name()="alinea"]

Comment: Nothing to do. "Invalid predicate". Thank you for your patience. I don't want to steal you other time.

Comment: for me it is giving result. i think there is problem with character encoding try retype local-name().

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `simplexml` but using `DOMDocument` with your XPath works for me:

```
<?php
$xmlString = '...';
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('a', 'http://www.normeinrete.it/nir/2.1/');
$nodes = $xpath->query('a:LeggeRegionale[@id="urn:nir:legge:2014-12-12;26"]/a:articolato/a:articolo[@id="art41"]/a:comma[@id="art41-com1"]/a:alinea');
print_r($nodes->item(0));
```